# register events on initial page with slient:true passed to backbone history start

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am building an app which does both client side and server side rendering. Initial page is rendered by the server and subsequent pages by backbone on the client. I do this by passing silent:true on the client history start method.

I don’t want the route to render/execute, fetch template,etc on the initial page but i want to register events on that initial page. Each page has its own set of events.

So, How do i register events on that initial page?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal Sorry if i dint make myself clear enough. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Backbone.history.start({silent: true})

// Call code to register your events here.
```

Not sure there's a "recommended" way to do what you're asking, just write code that somehow registers events right after you start the history.

Comment: yeah. i think i will have to by this approach.i was looking at some best practise. wondering how people do client and server side rendering in multi page backbone apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the `route` method on the router object and make it replace itself with the original router code and nothing else.

Not tested but something like:

```
MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  route: function() {
    this.route = __super__.route;
  }
});
```